# Blank cell is ignored and overwritten in Excel.Range using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, cells

have data in an excel file as shown below, where row 1 & 2 are considered as header row which will be copied when this particular file is split according to the first column.

[image]

After split the files look like as below:

[image] [image]

The **Problem** is that Column D's value is copied to the wrong column that is C in this case.

I presume I need to check if a cell is empty or null and put blank/null value to the new file during write. Question is how can incorporate that into my following code?

```
    private FileEntity GetFileObject(Excel.Range range)
    {
        FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity();
        fileEntity.RowValues = new List<RowEntity>();

        for (int rowCount = 1; rowCount <= range.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
        {
            RowEntity rowEntity = new RowEntity();
            rowEntity.ColumnValues = new List<string>();

            for (int columnCount = 1; columnCount <= range.Columns.Count; columnCount++)
            {
                if ((range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value != null)
                {
                    rowEntity.ColumnValues.Add((range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            fileEntity.RowValues.Add(rowEntity);
        }
        return fileEntity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
                if ((range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value != null)
                {
                    rowEntity.ColumnValues.Add((range.Cells[rowCount, columnCount] as Excel.Range).Value.ToString());
                }
                else
                    rowEntity.ColumnValues.Add(""); //just add this line. keeps the blank cell as created with empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because there are built-in efficiencies to the document structure that avoid wasting space. You have to inspect the cells for their reference (A1, B1, etc.) and then you can know where it came from and what to do with it.

```
      int rowIdx = 0;

      foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>().Skip(1))
      {
        rowIdx++;
        IEnumerable<Cell> thisRow = r.Elements<Cell>();

        foreach (var c in thisRow)
        {
          //This will tell you what cell you are looking at (A2, D14, whatever..)
          string cellRef = c.CellReference.ToString().Substring(0, 1);

          switch (cellRef)
          {
            case "A": 
              //do something...
              break;
            case "B": 
              //do something...
              break;
            case "C": 
              //do something...
              break;
        ....ETC.......
```

Comment: I just realized my code is using the Open XML SDK and you are using Interop. The issue is likely the same however. You should be able to find a cell's cell reference so you know what column it is.

Comment: Being a novice on this, I can marely use the code to work. Would you be kind to comment on my code and show a direction how that can be changed perhaps?